# How to pick random words in html

Tags: html

So, im completely new to programming. All i know is extremely basic stuff like hello world. Basically, what i want to do is I want be able to pick random words out of a list. I'm not really sure how to do this. Im definitely not asking anyone to write the whole thing for me, I just need a starting point. Right now I'm pretty lost. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The community guidelines don't allow you to create vague posts, however I can recommend you to start with this site. When I wasn't able to develop anything in html I grew up with some of the following links: https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

It does depend on how the list is "made".

If the list can be made by the programmer (thus static and not be altered by the user), you could do the following (copy and paste this into a .html file):

```
<html>
  <button onclick="randomizeFunction()">Randomize!!</button>
  
  <p>Random generated word is:</p>
  <p id="randomWord"></p>
</html>

<script>
const myList = ["List item 1", "List item 2", "List item 3", "List item 4", "List item 5"];

randomizeFunction()

function randomizeFunction() {
    document.getElementById("randomWord").innerHTML = myList[Math.floor(Math.random() * myList.length)]
}
</script>
```

Do note, this uses JavaScript as well! Most responsive websites are driven by it nowadays.

Javascript is the part between the **script** tags. For you to customize, change the items in *const myList*, between the [ ... ]. Make sure the [ ... ] stay and seperate items with a comma. Also, if you are to use words, make sure to quote them (making them strings), like I did.

By the way, most people don't mind to get their hands dirty and providing you with an example ('write the whole thing').

Keep going, programming is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You will need javascript for this rather than html.
I created a function for you, called Random Word Picker.

if you want to add javascript to a html page put it between these tags

```
<script> </script>
```

```
let theList = ["hello", "there", "john", "how", "are", "you", "doing"]


function randomWordPicker(aList){
    let theListLength = theList.length / 10
    let theAnswer = Math.floor( ( Math.random( ) * 10 ) * theListLength  ) 
    return aList[theAnswer]
}

let result = randomWordPicker(theList)
document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = result
console.log(result)
```

this function will pick a random word from the list and then display it to a h1 tag and to the console.